# Will compilation phase be invoked only once for multiple instances of the same angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have read at multiple places that the angularjs cmpialtion phase is invoked once only if the directive is inside an ng-repeat. What about the case when there are multiple instances of the (same) directive scattered across same page or may be different pages ? Will the compilation phase be invoked only once ?